# Doxygen won't index my C++ source - why not?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have some C++ source code with templates maybe like this - doxygen runs without errors but none of the documentation is added to the output, what is going on?

```
///
/// A class
///
class A
{
  ///
  /// A typedef
  ///
  typedef B<C<D>> SomeTypedefOfTemplates;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, so what is going on is the template instantiation is bogus. The ">>" like that is ambiguous and is meant to be a compile time error. You couldn't see it because maybe your compiler (VC++) let it slip by but I guess doxygen was stricter on that. Add a space like shown.

```
///
/// A class
///
class A
{
  ///
  /// A typedef
  ///
  typedef B<C<D> > SomeTypedefOfTemplates;
};
```

Comment: Yep, the >> gets interpreted as a right-shift operator.  C++0x will change this behavior, though.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Angle_bracket

Comment: Did you just ask your own question and answer it for the sake of it?

Answer (score 6):

Note that doxygen now supports closing a template with the right shift operator (since version 1.6.0).

Also see http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=560512 for a discussion on the problem and the solution implemented.